# Link quebrando digitando diretamente no navegador

Tags: angular, angular-routes

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em angular que está quebrando o link quando tem parâmetro e é digitado diretamente no navegador, somente ocorre quando é publicado no IIS, se eu fizer o mesmo no publicado em desenvolvimento no "ng serve" esse mesmo erro não ocorre, olhando no console do chrome o erro que me apresenta é "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", observei que no Sources todos os arquivos carregados estão carregando o index.html o que está gerando esse erro, se o link com parâmetro é gerado internamente pelo angular clicando em um Button ou Link ele funciona corretamente, mas mesmo esse link pressionando enter na barra do navegador ocorre esse mesmo problema.
No IIS estou usando o URL Rwriter para conseguir usar as rotas pelo navegador web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="./" />      
    </rule>
   </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

"http://www.checkbooking.com.br/checkinexpress/register/a" não chega a processar o arquivo .ts, já tentei colocar anguns logs, e também não passa pelo interceptor que criei

Comment: esse /checkingexpress e uma rota da usa aplicacao? Ou tipo o index esta la?

Comment: @EduardoVargas sim, o index está nessa rota, se acessar esse caminho ele redireciona para login

Comment: tenta fazer a build assim: ng build --base-href=/checkinexpress/

Comment: @EduardoVargas obrigado funcionou, posta a sua resposta que eu marco ela como a solução

Comment: link para auxiliar os demais [aqui](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sua url esta um level acima invés de seuSite.com esta seusite.com/algumacoisa

vc tem que fazer a build assim:

> ng build --base-href=/algumacoisa/

ou no seu caso

> ng build --base-href=/checkinexpress/